# Package development: how to include provider and aliases (Socialite)

Tags: php, laravel-5, package

I'm developing my first Larvel-based package. I want to include the Socialite package, so I put it like this in my `composer.json` file

```
"require": {
    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0"
},
```

Now, how do I include the provider and the alias as  you'd normally do in `/config/app.php` ?

I think by now I've read every stackoverflow there is about this matter, but nothing seems to work.

This is my package's serviceprovider:

```
public function boot()
    {
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';

        $this->app->register('Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider');
        $this->app->alias('Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite', 'Socialite');

        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../views', 'package-name');
        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../lang', 'package-name');
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../views' => resource_path('views/vendor/package-name'),
        ]);

        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../database/migrations/' => database_path('migrations')
        ], 'migrations');
    }
```

Result:

> Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found

**UPDATE**

```
"psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Rubenwouters\\CrmLauncher\\": "packages/rubenwouters/crm-launcher/src/"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your package's service provider in register method you can do:

```
public function boot() {
    $this->app->register(ClassOfScialiteServiceProvider);
    $this->app->alias(FacedeClass, 'Alias');
}
```

**EDIT**

But first of all... To add your package in the right way (to the vendor that you can adding a requirments) you have to some how add it to the main `composer.json` - `required` list. You can do it with one of below:

## 1

Adding you package to the official composer repository ([packagist](https://packagist.org/))

## 2

Make your own composer repository like [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis)

## 3

The easiest way is to add your git repo dependanci inside `composer.json` like:

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@your_repo/crm-launcher.git"
    },
],
"require": {
     (...)
     "rubenwouters/crm-launcher": "dev-master"
}
```

## OR

or just move your dependencies (`"laravel/socialite": "^2.0"`) to the main `composer.json`. :)

Comment: I'm sory. The register method is too fast. Try in `boot`. I've change it in my example.

Comment: I get the same "Class not found" error. :/ I've edited my question with the code of my own serviceprovider.

Comment: To be sure, where should I run this? In my package folder or in the main folder?

Comment: In the main folder. First of all how do you have added you package to the main composer.json

Comment: I've updated my question. There you can see how I've added my package to the main composer.json.

Comment: Ok. You did it in the wrong way. I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm still in developing phase. After my package is done, I want to submit my package for packagist/packalyst. So maybe it's best for now to use my git repo? 

Does this needs to go in the main composer.json?

But when I submit my package (when it's done), it still needs to be right in my code. So the aliases and providers still need to be published into the developers project. My point is: is using the git repo not just avoiding the problem?

Comment: Yes it's only avoiding the problem.  Best option for small projects is satis... you can learn on it how composer works... and about developing phase... it will last forever :) so there is no point for not doing it in right way... I working with packages all the time in few way

Comment: I understand what you're saying. However, this is not just another project for me. It's my final school project so it needs to be done the right way.

Comment: Great then... Satis is perfect for that... You will ge

Answer (score 0):

Register **Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,** to Config\app.php as providers and also 
Register **'Socialize' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,** to Config\app.php as aliases.

May be this will solve your problem.